# Translation of 'to whom it may concern'

Tags: traduction, anglais, correspondance

In English, "To whom it may concern" is a generic starter to a letter implying that the letter is addressed to anyone for whom the letter is relevant.

For a bit of context, I had to ask someone in France for a document confirming my workplace, and was thinking how I would word such a document in English. In English I would have started with "To whom it may concern" whereas the document I was given used a different approach "ATTESTATION", but it did get me thinking!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In French, to address a letter *to whom it may concern* I would use:

> Madame, Monsieur

Inside the text of the letter, you could use the *à qui de droit* translation:

- > You should forward this letter *to whom it may concern*
- > Vous pouvez transférer cette lettre *à qui de droit*

source: [Banque de dépannage linguistique de l'Office québecois de la langue française](http://66.46.185.79/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2099)

Answer (score 9):

In French, it's not correct to adress a letter *à qui de droit* ("to whom it may concern").

It is preferable tu use *Madame, Monsieur,* ("Dear Sir or Madam") if there is one person or *Mesdames, Messieurs,* ("Ladies and Gentlemen," but this translation is rather awkward) if there are several people, followed by a new paragraph.

Comment: Well, you still have to *address it* as in *put a name on the envelope* (or the top right of the letter as I usually do). So instead of « À Madame Dupont, 12 rue du général Quinexistepas, 12345 Trifoullis-les-oies », I usually put « À qui de droit » whenever I don’t know who will read it. Then, I **open** my letter with « Madame, Monsieur ».

Answer (score 7):

On top of other answers,

- Another translation of *to whom it may concern* is *aux intéressés*:

  > Merci de communiquer ces informations **aux intéressés**. (*Please communicate this information **to whom it may concern***)

  Should you read this a day, the meaning is basically the same as *à qui de droit*. The slight differences between the two are mostly a question of usage.

  For example, a legal request (permit, authorization...) needs approval from *qui de droit* while information can be communicated *aux intéressés* or *à qui de droit*.
- *Aux personnes concernées* is sometimes used as well but is less common. The meaning is the same as *aux intéressés*, in a lower register:

  > Merci de communiquer ces informations **aux personnes concernées**. (*Please communicate this information **to whom it may concern***)

Comment: Dans le sens de ce qu'on explique, voir aussi [ceci](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&codom2nd=&srchtxt=%E0+qui+de+droit&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0). Merci.

Answer (score 3):

Stumble into this thread as I couldn't figure out "To whom it may concern" in my native language when used as a starter for a non-personal mail (say, to an administration). It eventually struck me:

> À l'attention des personnes concernées

Comment: *À l'attention de* est généralement utilisé comme mention d'acheminement, moins souvent en début de correspondance.