# Formal treatment pronoun when sex is undefined

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

I'd like to write a Lettre de Présentation for a job offer, but I don't know who will read it. Also, according to a guide, expressions like "à qui de droit" are not a good idea.

I found "monsieur-dame" somewhere, but [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/monsieur-dame) says it is for couples.

So, what kind of expression would be fitting for such kind of document?

Comment: Welcome to FLU voyageur, I think we've already had this question and you'll find an answer  [there](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/2248/358). In your topic you announce "treatment pronoun" but in your answer it's not dery clear what you mean by that, you can edit your question if you want to add precisions concerning what bothers you in the pronoun treatment.

Comment: @Laure Yes, the link posted there explains it perfectly ( http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=2099 ). Thanks for your comments. You may close this question.

Comment: On the moderators @StéphaneGimenez will close the question, I can't. Do come back whenever you have a question about French Language.