# Lettre adressée à un destinataire inconnu

Tags: politesse, correspondance

Je suis en plein processus d'envoi de CV, et j'ai un léger problème au niveau des lettres de motivation.

Idéalement, je l'adresserais au nom de la personne en charge de l'embauche. Si ce destinaire est inconnu, je devrais opter pour "Madame, Monsieur". Jusque là, ça va.

Le problème, c'est que "Madame, Monsieur" est très formel. Si je souhaite soumettre ma candidature à une agence de jeunes professionnels créatifs, par exemple, l'utilisation de "Madame" ou "Monsieur" (à moins que ce terme soit suivi du nom de la personne en question) me semble un peu *out of place*, et rend la lettre un peu trop générique (style "j'ai téléchargé un *template* en ligne et changé la signature").

En anglais, j'ai trouvé qu'il est possible d'utiliser "Dear Hiring Manager" (ou quelconque variante de) dans le pire des cas. Le français a-t-il un équivalent acceptable, et si oui, quel est-il?

Comment: Je ne connais que la formule de politesse « Madame, Monsieur ». Je n'ai jamais entendu d'équivalent français à la formule anglaise proposée, hormis peut-être dans l'en-tête de la lettre (« À l'attention du gestionnaire des ressources humaines »). Si le but est de s'adresser à des créatifs, sortir totalement des sentiers battus et formules traditionnelles peut être une idée. La seule limite est alors l'irrespect : il serait dommage d'offusquer son interlocuteur avant même que celui-ci ait commencé à lire la lettre qui lui est adressée.

Comment: L'autre option que je connais (et utilisais il y a plusieurs années avant de comprende que c'était beaucoup trop impersonnel) est "à qui de droit", qui est l'équivalent du "to whom it may concern"...donc à éviter.

Comment: Cela fait effectivement un peu « bouteille à la mer ». Difficile d'engager une audience de cette façon. [Un exemple lié au domaine créatif](http://etudiant.aujourdhui.fr/etudiant/info/exemple-de-lettre-de-motivation-pour-une-inscription-en-manaa.html) utilise le traditionnel « Madame, Monsieur ». Sans rien savoir sur la personne qui lira la lettre, je pense qu'il est difficile de sortir de cette ornière tant elle est creusée.

Comment: Je crois que le terme officiel dans ce cas est "Messieurs,". (oui au pluriel).

Comment: Dans quel domaine s'exerce la créativité juvénile ?

Comment: En fait, le simple fait d'envoyer une lettre de motivation me semble déjà décalé par rapport à une agence créative... Si ils en demandent une je me poserais déjà des questions sur eux, et s'ils n'en demandent pa,s en envoyer une sera plutôt perçu négativement je pense. Cela dit, si tu tiens à/dois en faire une,  pourquoi pas un simple "Bonjour, ", ou alors essayer de te démarquer (être créatif) "Au petit veinard qui lira ceci,", ... Les offres d'emploi de telles agences (les bonnes en tout cas) sont elle-aussi généralement moins "standard" que pour le reste des jobs.

Comment: Spécifiquement sur [« à qui de droit »](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/2248); à ne pas utiliser dans l'appel. Merci.

Comment: I'd really watch out for 'dear hiring manager' in English if I were you :-).  Soo stuffy.. On the other hand, you can almost never be too stuffy in France.  The ones who'll be amused by 'cher pote creatif, voila mon cv' will be vastly outnumbered by the ones who want a 'madame, monsieur'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il n'y a pas de variante équivalente parce que « *Dear Hiring Manager* » n'est pas informel à mon avis. En [anglais](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect10&info0=10.17#zz10) les formules les plus formelles peuvent contenir « [*Dear*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&srchtxt=DEAR%20SIR%20MADAM) » (*Dear Sir or Madam*); ce n'est pas le cas en [français](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect8&info0=8.1.8#zz8). À mon avis la tournure anglaise présentée ne fait qu'utiliser un [*titre*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&__index=alt&srchtxt=HIRING%20MANAGER). Si on ne connaît pas le nom, le sexe ou le titre de la personne à qui l'on s'adresse, il n'y a aucune raison d'utiliser moins que la formule d'appel *usuelle* ([F](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/madame) / [M](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/monsieur)) : « **Madame, Monsieur,** ». Le degré de civilité ne change pas selon le domaine du destinataire et ne s'oppose à sa créativité; de plus le contexte même de la lettre de motivation est celui de la rédaction dans le domaine des affaires. La formule « À qui de droit » ne constitue pas une option et ne peut être utilisée dans un *appel*; il ne faut pas confondre le contenu de l'[*appel*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3309) de celui de la [*vedette*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?th=2&id=2096) dans une [*lettre*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3309). Si on connaît le titre du destinataire (par ex. *le Directeur/la Directrice*), on peut l'utiliser avec *Monsieur* ou *Madame* dans l'appel.

Je ne pense pas personnellement qu'une ligne ou deux rendent une lettre générique ou que la formule usuelle ne soit pas adaptée et qu'il faille se démarquer à ce niveau. On pourra utiliser le corps de la lettre ou carrément un autre document selon le domaine (par ex. un *portfolio*), ou l'entrevue pour personnaliser davantage.

Comment: Excellente réponse, merci! Pour justifier un peu ma question: dans un cas récent, j'ai eu l'opportunité de parler de vive voix à la personne en charge du recrutement, qui m'a explicitement demandé de la tutoyer (...à deux reprises), donc j'essayais de trouver un "middle ground" à l'écrit.

Comment: @Nils Le tutoiement est assez courant dans certains milieux professionnels mais pas systématique. Je choisis personnellement une approche _safe_ : j'utilise le vouvoiement jusqu'à ce que les usages m'indiquent le contraire (si mon interlocuteur m'y invite ou me tutoie sans être mon supérieur, par exemple). Ceci arrive rarement avant la première entrevue ou un échange téléphonique. À cette étape, on connais déjà le nom de l'interlocuteur et il est possible de lui adresser le courrier personnellement. L'appel n'est donc plus un problème. En attendant, la formalité pose rarement problème.

Comment: Excellent, merci! C'est effectivement l'approche que j'ai habituellement. Venant de terminer des études additionnelles, j'ai passé un petit bout de temps sans faire de recherche d'emploi, donc je souhaitais vérifier si j'étais "à jour".

Comment: @Nils Je vous en prie. Merci. Je comprends mieux... Il est important de bien cerner le sens de l'expression anglaise et de présenter le contexte avec ce genre de question ; le défi pour moi était de cerner le _dear_ en anglais. Si on parle à une personne de vive voix, c'est une occasion de prendre en note le nom et le titre et d'envoyer à l'attention de cette personne directement ; mais pour moi ça ne change rien dans le ton usuel de la correspondance formelle à l'écrit. Je saisis l'idée de ne pas être distant ; pour moi c'est davantage dans le comportement que ça se manifeste. Bonne chance !

Answer (score 0):

En anglais quand on ne connait pas le destinataire, on peut ouvrir une lettre avec la formule suivante (qui parait aride en français mais qui est très utilisée en anglais) :

> To whom it may concern,

Comment: Ce n'est pas aussi aride en anglais? (Malgré le fait qu'on l'utilise?)

Comment: Et en français comment est-ce que ça répond à la question ?  La réponse de user3177 a traité *a qui de droit* par exemple.